# Converting JSON ARRAY into NSNumber Arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, json, nsarray, nsnumber

I've retrieved data from a JSON web service and saved it into the following array
_soldamount = 
(
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    "62.69",
    "48.3",
    81,
    "59.83",
    "162.57",
    0,
    "40.67",
)
I believe this array is saved as a string. how can I convert this array into an array of NSnumbers? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Perhaps you should show the JSON data.

Comment: @MartinR - No need.  The JSON data is `["0", "0", "0", "0", "62.69", "48.3", "81", "59.83", "162.57", "0", "40.67"...]`.

Comment: The easiest solution would probably be to iterate through your array and convert each element from NSString to NSNumber using [NSNumber numberWithFloat:element.floatValue];

Comment: @MartinR nice use of KVC. The class of each object changed from NSCFConstantString to NSCFNumber.

Comment: @Chris: Well, it has advantages and disadvantages. It is less code, but for example a typo in the key path will lead to a runtime exception, whereas a typo in an explicit loop would not compile ...

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *_soldamount = @[ @0, @0, @0, @0, @"62.69", @"48.3", @81, @"59.83", @"162.57", @0, @"40.67"];
NSArray *numbers = [_soldamount valueForKey:@"doubleValue"];
```

creates an array of `NSNumber`s. The original array can contain `NSNumber` 
or `NSString` objects.

Comment: I think he wants to get these values from the JSON, not hardcode them.

Comment: @Gavin: It was just meant as an example how to convert an array of strings to an array of numbers. Of course it can be that I misunderstood the problem.

Comment: You are converting the fractional numbers into integers.

Comment: This still doesn't answer the question, because this isn't parsing the JSON at all.

Comment: @Gavin: You might be right, that's why I asked for the "original" JSON data. However, I had a look at user3178926's previous questions now and that looks to me as if the JSON parsing part is already done. - Perhaps we have just answered different parts of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the following code:

```
NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *e = nil;
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&e];
```

What is stored in the `json` variable will depend on the JSON data. It is most commonly either an `NSDictionary` or `NSArray`, and it looks like yours would be an `NSArray` probably.

Comment: That doesn't solve the OP's problem -- the data in the resulting NSArray will be strings, not NSNumbers.

Comment: I disagree. He can get out any of them, whether stored as an `NSNumber` or `NSString`, as a double, by calling the method `-doubleValue`, which either `NSNumber` or `NSString` will respond to. That would be the end goal, anyway, if you wanted to access their values, so it doesn't matter whether the JSON is returning them properly as numbers or not.

Comment: The OP asked for an array of NSNumbers.

Answer (score 0):

If these values are intended to be stored as numbers, your web service should be returning them as such.  In other words, a value with quotes (") around it is a string regardless of whether or not the string is numerical.

If you do not have control of the web service and still wish to store these values as NSNumbers, you can use `[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[string floatValue]]` or you may wish to use `[string doubleValue]` if the strings may contain large values or high precision floating point values.

See Gavin's answer on how to use the NSJSONSerialization class if you aren't using it already.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization 
    JSONObjectWithData:responseData
    options:kNilOptions
    error:&error];
NSArray *soldAmount = [json objectForKey:@"amount"]; // Your array of strings.
// Convert string array to number array
NSMutableArray *numberArray = [NSMutableArray array];
[soldAmount enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [numberArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[(NSString *)obj floatValue]]];
}];
```

Answer (score -2):

use [NSnumber numberWithInteger:[string integerValue]]

Comment: This doesn't accomplish what the question is asking about.

Comment: It is sort of correct, though it again makes the mistake of integerizing the fractional data.

Comment: No, he has a string that contains a block of JSON that consists of an array with values in it. This code wouldn't do anything with it. I think calling `integerValue` on the array will return `0`, because it'll immediately encounter non-numerical values in the string. So he'll have an `NSNumber` containing the number `0`.

Comment: @Gavin - I take `string` to be the value of an array entry.  In that case, if the entry is numeric, at least the integer portion will be parsed and returned.